# Manually updating FF Add-ons

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, add-on

My application installs my Firefox add-on (by copying an my.xpi to [FF_inst_dir]\extensions).
This application interact with my FF add-on.
This application periodically has updates (.xpi with new version).
When my application is updating it does next:

1. Remove folder and content [FF_inst_dir]\extensions\MyExtension
2. Copy new my.xpi to [FF_inst_dir]\extensions

However, when I restart FF I see:

1. FF ask me about install add-on. I agree.
2. FF remove my.xpi (it's ok)
3. FF remove folder and content [FF_inst_dir]\extensions\MyExtension
   I think that FF try to remove old plugin.

Thus, I havn't installed plugin.

How it can be installed correct?

Answer (score 1):

We aren't going to support dropping XPIs into the extensions directories like this in the future. Also please please do not use the application's extensions directory for this. Instead [extract your extension's files into one of the shared locations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Installing_extensions) or to a [directory pointed to by the registry](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Adding_Extensions_using_the_Windows_Registry).

Comment: As I can see, If I want to install extension for all users I have to use the second method.
Yes ?

So, how I can update installed extension ?
If I replace old version of extension with new version what will happend ? Will FF ask all users about updating ?

Comment: Either of the methods installs for all users or all profiles for a single user depending on the directory/registry key you use. Just update your extension's files in place and Firefox should detect the update on next startup.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with Firefox's built-in installation & update methods? At it's simplest, you browse to a web page and download the .xpi to install.

Is there a reason you can't post your extension to the Mozilla Add-ons site? If so, that would get you both easy installation and automatic updates when you post new versions.

Comment: I have to install a new version of the add-on only simultaneously with the updating of my windows application.